# Text Editor widget styling in Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

This is probably a dumb thing, but it drives me absolutely crazy that in the midst of my beautiful Material-themed data entry page in my App Maker app, the font for the text editor widget shows up as Times New Roman. It hurts me!

I've tried adding font-family styling for both `.app-TextEditor` and `.app-TextEditor-Body`, but it doesn't seem to touch it (see below). Has anyone figured this out?

[image]

Edited to Add: I know the user can set the font in the text editor window itself; I want a way to set the default as something other than Times.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the option in the Text-Editor widget itself. Refer below image, there is an option to change font type, size etc.

[image: Font-Type]

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just hoping to find a way to set the default as a specific font.

Comment: Yeah! For the first time you have to do it manually, next time on wards it will stay as per changes.